# FragmentPagerAdapterのFragmentの更新について

Tags: android, java, android-fragments

`ViewPager`を使用して5ページの`Fragment`を切り替えているのですが、あるタイミングで各 `Fragment` 内の `ArrayList` の要素を全て書き換えて反映させたいのですが、`Fragment` が非表示中に更新すると更新が反映されません。

各`Fragment`内では`RecyclerView`を使用しています。この `RecyclerView` の `Adapter` の要素を一度に更新したいです。

各 `Fragment` クラス内の更新用メソッド内で

```
if (mTextView != null) { 
    //Fragmentがactive 
    mList = tmpList; 
} else { 
    //Fragmentがdetachされている 
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
    bundle.putString("key","value"); 
    setArugments(bundle) 
}
```

としているのですが、うまく整合性がとれません。

非表示から再表示時に更新された `List` 値を使用して初期化したいのですが、いい方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: ListViewにadapterをセットする処理をonCreateView()からonActivityCreated()に移すのはどうでしょうか

Comment: もう少しコードがあったほうが回答しやすいかと思います。